# Is it possible to block the access of a super user?

Tags: postgresql

In a scenario that the databases run on the client's server.

Company "A" has a database installed on that server. The customer hires the services of a company "B", which will also install its database on the server.

If company "B" uses a super user, it can have access to the company "A" database. It may even try to harm company "A" by changing information in the database.

Is there a way to block super user access to company "A" database?

Comment: Don't give them access to super user!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That should be easy. Put the databases in different PostgreSQL clusters on the same server.

But even if both databases are in the same cluster, a superuser can only access the database if there is a line in `pg_hba.conf` that allows it. So you can achieve the goal with a properly configured `pg_hba.conf` file. That requires that the superuser is known by name – you cannot add a line that says “block all superusers from that database”.

Comment: The different clusters should be owned by different OS users.  Otherwise, it is possible to leverage superuser access on one cluster to access a different one.  But really, I think this is bringing a knife to a lawyer fight.  If you are worried company B is hostile, don't do business with them or at least don't let them inside your network.

Comment: The client who hires company "B", so we have no control over that. It's a small client, they don't have a specialized IT team. Then they pass the server access to company "B" to do the installation. That is, company "B" can do whatever it wants on the server.

Comment: The question is whether you want to defend yourself against malice or folly. A malicious superuser can do everything the PostgreSQL operating system user can. A foolish superuser also can bring the machine to its knees, so using different machines that don't share storage (or using Linux control groups to limit bandwidth) is the safest way.